Manhwa about a cursed, blue-eyed girl who runs away from her village into a forest, where she meets the male lead
Could someone help me find this manhwa / manga?
The female lead (FL) is somewhat a cursed, blue-eyed village girl. Because of her curse, she was forced to engage with one of the village boys. The village boy tried to rape her, so she fought back and ran away into he forest where she met the male lead (ML).
The ML is a special being (either a dragon / fox / demon). The FL tried to fight back but the ML captured the FL, as he sensed something that he has been searching for from her. The FL tried to escaped, so she was punished by being whipped on the back of her body. The FL still tried to escape, despite her weakened body, but was captured and saved by the ML. The ML removed her clothes to cure her back wounds, which made the FL feel shy.
I'm not sure how the story goes next, but eventually, the FL tried to save someone from the ML by sacrificing herself and made her transform into somewhat of a fated person that was supposed to save the ML cursed.

Did you intend something in your title after the "and"?

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the male lead?
